# What to do if my question is very similar to another but isn't answered there?

Tags: support, asking-questions, exact-duplicates

I have a doubt about the following: Suppose I want to ask some question, but Math.SE already has one that is very similar (say 90% similar). The chances that my question will be closed as duplicate are really high, but what if the other question doesn't answer my question in particular?

There's a good example: I was to ask about a hint to prove that continuous images of compact sets are compact, but soon I've found that there already is another question regarding this problem. The point is that the only answer to the question doesn't answer what I'm needing, and so I didn't post the question to avoid having it as duplicate.

What should I do in cases like that?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Related: [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer) and
[What to do when one wants to “revive” a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9242/what-to-do-when-one-wants-to-revive-a-question).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Post your question and include a link to the other question along with a short explanation why the other thread *does not address your issues*. If possible, explain even further what you *are* looking for in an answer.

That should be enough.